# How to find the closest point given the Voronoi relevant vectors?

Tags: lattices, lattice-theory, lattice-polytopes

Let M be the generator matrix of a $N\times N$ lattice, and $\tilde{N}$ the set of Voronoi relevant vectors. The Voronoi cell for the origin can be written as $\text{Vor}_{\bf 0}(M)=\left\{{\bf x}: |{\bf x}|\leq|{\bf x-c}|\text{ for } \forall {\bf c}\in \tilde{N}\right\}$. My question is given $\tilde{N}$, how to find the closest lattice vector for a given point ${\bf x}\in R^N$? Equivalently, given $\tilde{N}$, how to translate the given point ${\bf x}$ back to $\text{Vor}_{\bf 0}$?

If $\tilde{N}$ is not given, the closest point can be found with the algorithm introduced [here](https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/14990/local_14990.pdf), and the same algorithm can be modified to find $\tilde{N}$. The motivation for my question is that I would like to find the closest points for a large number of ${\bf x}$'s, for the same lattice. Running the closest point search algorithm is very expensive, hence I am hoping to use relevant vectors to find the closest points.

This is my attempt to translate a given point ${\bf x}$ back to $\text{Vor}_{\bf 0}$ given the relevant vectors $\tilde{N}$

```
for c in $\tilde{N}$
    overlap = x^T * c/norm(c)^2 
    if abs(overlap) > 1/2
        x = x - round(overlap) * c
    end
end
```

which seems working for 2D lattices, but not for 3D lattices. Hence I am not sure if the algorithm is correct, or if it is possible to do that for general lattices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe state of the art for this is [Short Paths on the Voronoi Graph and Closest Vector
Problem with Preprocessing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6168) by Bonifas and Dadush.
For instance, see the following quote from the abstract

> Our main technical contribution is a randomized procedure that given the Voronoi relevant vectors of a lattice - the lattice vectors inducing facets of the Voronoi cell - as preprocessing and any "close enough" lattice point to the target, computes a path to a closest lattice vector of expected polynomial size. This improves on the $\tilde{O}(4^n)$ path length given by the MV algorithm. Furthermore, as in MV, each edge of the path can be computed using a single iteration over the Voronoi relevant vectors.

This is to say that Bonifas+Dadush should imply a (randomized) algorithm of complexity $O(\mathsf{poly}(N)|\tilde{N}|)$ (as a side note, using $N$ for a dimension and $\tilde{N}$ for a set is perhaps not the best choice of notation).
Note that this may not mean *efficient*, as $|\tilde{N}|$ can grow exponentially in $N$.
But, if you have a lattice for which you know that $|\tilde{N}|$ is small, it should efficiently solve your problem.

Note that one can often solve CVP efficiently even in lattices that have exponentially many Voronoi relevant vectors.
This is true if they have small *extension complexity*, see [Lifts for Voronoi Cells of Lattices](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.04432) by Schymura, Seidel, and Weltge.

It's also worth mentioning that there have been improvements for finding $\tilde{N}$.
In particular, see [A Deterministic Single Exponential Time Algorithm for Most Lattice Problems](http://cse.ucsd.edu/sites/cse/files/cse/assets/research/theory/MicciancioVoulgaris_2010_stoc.pdf) by Micciancio+Voulgaris.

Comment: This is so useful, many thanks! Let me make sure I understand it correctly. For my problem, namely, finding the closest points for like 10^6 random given points for a given lattice, there are the following three approaches

1. Using the closest point search algorithm for all the points [as in this 2002 paper](https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/14990/local_14990.pdf)

2. Using the MV algorithm with the relevant vectors as the additional input

3. Using the Bonifas+Dadush randomized algorithm

The needed runtime is lowered as in this order. Is that right?

Comment: I probably won't need the state-of-the-art randomized algorithm for now. If MV is better than naively running the closest point search 10^6 times, then it will be awesome!

Comment: Yes, that is my impression, though there are likely more efficient things you can do when you have to compute CVP for many points at once (though I don't know if anyone has written about it).

Comment: Another question/clarification regarding the time complexity. The time complexity for the above three approaches are respectively 10^6 * n^(n/2), 10^6 * 4^n and 10^6 * 2^n, right? I include the 10^6 factor to make sure I get it right, and let us assume no other tricks or parallelism involved here.

Comment: It depends on how large $|\tilde{N}|$ is. In particular, the Bonifas + Dadush result should have complexity roughly $10^6|\tilde{N}|\mathsf{poly}(N)$, i.e. (for certain $\tilde{N}$) not even exponential in $N$.

Comment: Oh yeah, you mentioned above. Thanks!